Problem of alignining a system of equations
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{aligned}
    & (x+y)(x-y) = 35 \Longleftrightarrow (x+y)(x-y) = 35 \times 1 = 7 \times 5 \\
    & \overset{0 \leq x - y \leq x + y}{\Longleftrightarrow}  
        \begin{cases}
            x + y = 35 \\ 
            x - y = 1 
        \end{cases}
        \quad \text{ou} \quad
        \begin{cases}
            x + y = 7 \\ 
            x - y = 5
        \end{cases} \\
    & \Longleftrightarrow \quad 
        \begin{cases}
            2x = 36 \\
            2y = 34
        \end{cases}
        \quad \text{ou} \quad
        \begin{cases}
            2x = 12 \\ 
            2y = 2
        \end{cases} \\
    & \Longleftrightarrow \quad 
        \begin{cases}
            x = 18 \\
            y = 17
        \end{cases}
        \quad \text{ou} \quad
        \begin{cases}
            x = 6 \\ 
            y = 1
        \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}

I get

I have spent an hour trying to figure out how to get the following alignement.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Why would you want to get the latter alignment? Yours one is much better.

@SergeiGolovan Thanks a lot. It is from a book and I thought that it is more 'professional' looking. So I do not change anything! I appreciate your remark.

The second picture you show is really bad typesetting. No alignment is even tried and the space around the = signs is completely wrong. In simpler terms, it's a mess and not an example to imitate.
I'd center the bottom part with respect to the top line
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\oLongleftrightarrow}{%
  \overset{\hphantom{0 \leq x - y \leq x + y}}{\Longleftrightarrow}
}
\begin{gathered}
  (x+y)(x-y) = 35 \Longleftrightarrow (x+y)(x-y) = 35 \times 1 = 7 \times 5
\\
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
    & \overset{0 \leq x - y \leq x + y}{\Longleftrightarrow}
    & \quad &
      \begin{cases}
        x + y = 35 \\ 
        x - y = 1 
      \end{cases}
    && \text{ou} \quad
      \begin{cases}
        x + y = 7 \\ 
        x - y = 5
      \end{cases} \\
    & \oLongleftrightarrow
    & \quad &
      \begin{cases}
        2x = 36 \\
        2y = 34
      \end{cases}
    && \text{ou} \quad
      \begin{cases}
        2x = 12 \\ 
        2y = 2
      \end{cases} \\
    & \oLongleftrightarrow
    & \quad &
      \begin{cases}
        x = 18 \\
        y = 17
      \end{cases}
    && \text{ou} \quad
      \begin{cases}
        x = 6 \\ 
        y = 1
      \end{cases}
  \end{alignedat}
\end{gathered}
\]

\end{document}

A local command has been defined to ease input. It's only valid in that display environment.
I also exploit the fact that there is already a \quad at the right of cases when no side condition is used.

(I'm not really a fan of such a way to present solution of equations.)
A visual comparison
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\section{Plain presentation}

Let's be given that $x^2-y^2=35$. Then we have
\[
(x+y)(x-y) = 35 \times 1 = 7 \times 5
\]
Under the assumption that $x-y\ge0$, which implies $x+y\ge x-y$, there are two cases:
\[
\systeme{x+y=35,x-y=1}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\systeme{x+y=7,x-y=5}
\]
In the first case we get $2x=36$ and $2y=34$, hence $x=18$ and $y=17$. 
In the second case we get $2x=12$ and $2y=2$, hence $x=6$ and $y=1$.


\section{Only symbols}

\[
\newcommand{\oLongleftrightarrow}{%
  \overset{\hphantom{0 \leq x - y \leq x + y}}{\Longleftrightarrow}
}
\begin{gathered}
  (x+y)(x-y) = 35 \Longleftrightarrow (x+y)(x-y) = 35 \times 1 = 7 \times 5
\\
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
    & \overset{0 \leq x - y \leq x + y}{\Longleftrightarrow}
    & \quad &
      \begin{cases}
        x + y = 35 \\ 
        x - y = 1 
      \end{cases}
    && \text{ou} \quad
      \begin{cases}
        x + y = 7 \\ 
        x - y = 5
      \end{cases} \\
    & \oLongleftrightarrow
    &&
      \begin{cases}
        2x = 36 \\
        2y = 34
      \end{cases}
    && \text{ou} \quad
      \begin{cases}
        2x = 12 \\ 
        2y = 2
      \end{cases} \\
    & \oLongleftrightarrow
    & \quad &
      \begin{cases}
        x = 18 \\
        y = 17
      \end{cases}
    && \text{ou} \quad
      \begin{cases}
        x = 6 \\ 
        y = 1
      \end{cases}
  \end{alignedat}
\end{gathered}
\]

\end{document}


